# Attribute Error initialising Ray in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, ray

My python environment details are below. This is a conda virtual env that I created just to test ray core as on this [Ray getting started tutorial](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-overview/getting-started.html). Initialising Ray throws the error: "AttributeError: module 'pydantic._internal' has no attribute '_model_construction'".

I have tried other environments, and got the same error (details below). Any ideas? Is this a known bug?

```
Python 3.10.13 (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:44:35) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
>>ray.__version__
'2.8.0'
>> pydantic.__version__
'2.5.2
>> ray.init()

2023-11-28 16:23:34,931 ERROR services.py:1329 -- Failed to start the dashboard , return code 1
2023-11-28 16:23:34,932 ERROR services.py:1354 -- Error should be written to 'dashboard.log' or 'dashboard.err'. We are printing the last 20 lines for you. See 'https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-observability/ray-logging.html#logging-directory-structure' to find where the log file is.
2023-11-28 16:23:34,932 ERROR services.py:1398 -- 
The last 20 lines of /tmp/ray/session_2023-11-28_16-23-33_263520_17288/logs/dashboard.log (it contains the error message from the dashboard): 
  File ".../miniconda3/envs/ray_env/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/dashboard/modules/job/cli.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ray.job_submission import JobStatus, JobSubmissionClient
  File "/home/zhubarb/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/job_submission/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ray.dashboard.modules.job.pydantic_models import DriverInfo, JobDetails, JobType
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/dashboard/modules/job/pydantic_models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ray._private.pydantic_compat import BaseModel, Field, PYDANTIC_INSTALLED
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/_private/pydantic_compat.py", line 100, in <module>
    monkeypatch_pydantic_2_for_cloudpickle()
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/_private/pydantic_compat.py", line 58, in monkeypatch_pydantic_2_for_cloudpickle
    pydantic._internal._model_construction.SchemaSerializer = (
AttributeError: module 'pydantic._internal' has no attribute '_model_construction'
2023-11-28 16:23:36,064 INFO worker.py:1673 -- Started a local Ray instance.
[2023-11-28 16:23:36,983 E 17288 17288] core_worker.cc:205: Failed to register worker 01000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff to Raylet. IOError: [RayletClient] Unable to register worker with raylet. No such file or directory
```